# it's been two years... + present perfect or simple past?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which of These two sentences is preferable?

> It's been two years since I last saw her.
>
> It's been two years I haven't seen her.

Are they both correct?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that:

> It's been two years since I last saw her.

is the correct sentence. The other sentence doesn't make sense to me as a native English speaker without some additional punctuation, like:

> It's been two years - I haven't seen her.
>
> It's been two years. I haven't seen her.

Comment: `since` is implying present perfect

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann It is, and the present perfect is indeed present in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

as I've learnt about the since and for with past simple, we can have the structure : It's + time since + past simple. therefore, the answer is the first one. I've never heard after since is a present perfect, we usually use past simple after since.